# Creating cache for a php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I'm running a php script that pulls data from MySQL table. I will be running this on a frequently visited server and would like to to keep the data in cache for X amount of time. So once you pull it, the data gets saved on the server and while the time has not passed. Here's the script:

```
<?php
include('mysql_connection.php');

$c = mysqlConnect();

$locale = $_GET['locale'];
$last_news_id = $_GET['news_id'];

sendQuery ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
sendQuery ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'"); 

if(strcmp($locale,"ru") != 0)
    $locale = "en";
$result = sendQuery("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id > ".$last_news_id." and locale = '".$locale."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
echo '<table width=\"100%\">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\"><b>Date: </b>'.$row[2].'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\">'.preg_replace('/#([^#]*)#(.*)/', ' <a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>', $row[3]).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\"><hr style="height: 2px; border: none; background: #515151;"></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

mysqliClose($c);
```

?>

What php functions to use to cache the data? What are the best methods? Thank you!

Comment: you could use APC http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: Why escape your double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php Memcache:
Just add this code in your script after "sendQuery()" funciton and store it in cache like below:

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('memcache_host', 11211);
memcache_set($memcache_obj, 'var_key', $result, 0, 30);
echo memcache_get($memcache_obj, 'var_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

The two go-to solutions are APC and Memcache. The former is also an opcache and the latter can be distributed. Pick what suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, your data already saved on the server.
And such a query should be pretty fast.

So, it seems that caching is unnecessary here. Especially if you experiencing no load problems but doing it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Apc/Memcached can be used and are used generally for this type of things. You have to be aware though about the problems that might arise from this approach: managing new inserts/updates and so on. As long as you don't really care about this information, you can set up arbitrary intervals for which the data will expire, but if the information is really relevant to your application, then this approach will not work.

Also, mysql already caches selects that are not modified between 2 requests, so basicly, if you do a select now, and one in 10 minutes with the exact same query, if nothing changed in the table, you will get the result from the query cache of mysql. There is still the overhead of issuing a data request and receiving data, but it is extremly fast. This approach works by default with the update/delete problem, because whenever a record in the table has modified, the associated query caches get erased, so you will get all modifications as they are.

Comment: So this script I have technically shouldn't put too much load on the server even if I get about 1000 visits a day?

Comment: For 1000 visits a day definetly not. It is way to low to cause any potential problems. Usually the problems appear on high concurrency combined with high traffic. The ideea of a caching system is not to cache everything. It is to discover the areas that can be improved with caching, wile considering the disadvantages (because there are disadvantages as mentioned above).